# Can i search any person in linkedin with API or only people near me?

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am using the library linkedin-j to use the linkedin API in Java. I am testing the search functionality but it seems that only return people near me, and I need to search people who has not relation with me, or people from any university or something like that.

I am using this code:

```
 Map<SearchParameter, String> searchParameters = new EnumMap<SearchParameter, String>(SearchParameter.class);
 searchParameters.put(SearchParameter.KEYWORDS, "University of X");        

 People people = client.searchPeople(searchParameters);
 System.out.println("Total search result:" + people.getCount());

 for (Person person : people.getPersonList()) {
     System.out.println(person.getId() + ":" + person.getFirstName() + " " +
     person.getLastName() + ":" + person.getHeadline());
 }
```

It returns me nothing.

However if i put my lastname in the parameters.

```
    searchParameters.put(SearchParameter.LAST_NAME, "MYLASTNAME");
```

It returns me only me.

Please, how can i search more people with this API?

Answer (score 0):

You must look for the [dev](http://developer.linkedin.com/) for more details.
According to me linked provides us access only to 1st degree connections. You can use the LinkedIn [REST  console](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/rest-console/) to try out more...
Hope this helps you.

Comment: No, it does not. Using REST console and searching for the same keyword i obtain nothing. http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?last-name=ANY_LASTNAME, i obtain nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To access people out of the network use Factes

```
 if(!searchParameters.isEmpty()) {
              System.out.println("Searching for users.");
             facets  = new ArrayList<Parameter<FacetType,String>>();
             facets.add(new Parameter<FacetType, String>(FacetType.NETWORK, RelationshipCodes.FIRST_DEGREE_CONNECTIONS));
              facets.add(new Parameter<FacetType, String>(FacetType.NETWORK, RelationshipCodes.OUT_OF_NETWORK_CONNECTIONS));
              facets.add(new Parameter<FacetType, String>(FacetType.NETWORK, RelationshipCodes.SECOND_DEGREE_CONNECTIONS));



            }
```

Use Following Api to acess profile attribute other than firstname,lastname,id.

```
 peopleSearch = client.searchPeople(searchParameters, EnumSet.of(ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.HEADLINE,ProfileField.DISTANCE), EnumSet.of(FacetField.NAME, FacetField.CODE, FacetField.BUCKET_NAME, FacetField.BUCKET_CODE, FacetField.BUCKET_COUNT), facets);
```